# Get first and fifth business day for each month

Tags: javascript

Any example of code or function which would tell if the indicative date is the 1st or 5th business day of the current month.

Business days are Monday - Friday

Example. By passing the current date of format `yyyy-MM-dd` the function or code could return true if the current date corresponds to 1st or 5th business day.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: I'm not very strong in java scripts, but have been playing with this script  '    function isBusinessDay(){
    var d=new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();
    switch(day) {
        case 0:
            return "Today is Weekend";
        break;
        case 6:
        return "Today is Weekend";
            break;
            default:
            return "Today is business day";
        }
           }'

Comment: Let me tweak my question a bit in a different way - How to check if the current day is the 1st or 5th business day of the current month?

Comment: You should add code to your question. Code should not be posted to comments. Furthermore, you didn't specify what happens if such a day is a public holiday.

Comment: I'll make note of that. Good point... yes, I need to consider if the 1st and 5th business day is public.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but it will work:

```
function checkIfFirstFithBusinessDay(day, month, year) {

    // check that it is a valid date
    if (!isNaN(day) && !isNaN(month) && !isNaN(year) && month > 0 && month < 13 && day > 0 && day < 32) {

        var d = new Date(year, month-1, day);

        // If the day does not much, that means that the original date was incorrect (e.g.: Feb 30)
        if (d.getDate() != day) { return false; }

        // month - 1, because months in JavaScript go from 0 (January) to 11 (December)
        var auxDate = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
        var first, fifth;

        switch (d.getDay()) {
            case 0: // the 1st of the month is Sunday --> first business day is the 2nd (Monday)
                first = 2; fifth = 6;
                break;
            case 6: // the 1st of the month is Saturday --> first business day is the 3rd (Monday)
                first = 3; fifth = 7;
                break;
            default:
                first = 1; fifth = 5;
                if      ((d.getDay() + fifth + 6) % 7 == 0) { fifth = 6; } // sunday
                else if ((d.getDay() + fifth + 6) % 7 == 6) { fifth = 7; } // saturday
                break;
        }

        var firstBusinessDay = new Date(year, month-1, first);
        var fifthBusinessDay = new Date(year, month-1, fifth);

        return (d.getTime() === firstBusinessDay.getTime() || d.getTime() === fifthBusinessDay.getTime());

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

And then, you just need to call the function: `firstAndFithBusinessDay(28, 12, 2000)`.

Just a few things:

- The parameters are day, month and year respectively (European style).
- This solution does not take into account holidays.
- You can easily change the code to detect if it's the first or fifth business day.

Comment: So here's is what I have  `var d=new Date();  
var day = d.getDay();  
if (day !=0 && day !=6)  
return "Weekday";`

Comment: The code that you keep including is nice, but it shows no effort from your side. Did you try making the changes that I suggested on my original post?

Comment: Your code does help, but not completely. Let me be straight up with you, I'm not into JavaScript but have a specific requirement that I am working on using JavaScript, hence I posted my question and it's not for any school assignment. I would love to go deep into scripting language but can't due to time constraint.  

All I need to know is an example which would tell me if the "current date is the 1st or 5th business date of the current month."

Comment: So let me get this right: you want some code/function that given a date, it will indicate if that date corresponds to the 1st or 5th business day in the month. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.  For example, I pass the current date `yyyy-MM-dd` and the function or code could return `true` if the current date corresponds to 1st or 5th business day

Comment: Done. You should update the question to reflect what you just said in the last comment.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

My interest was piqued by your question.

This is by no means perfect, but it did ok in some quick tests. 
You should invoke it as `getNthBusinessDay(5, 9, 2014)` for the 5th working day of Sept 2014.  In this case it returns the text `Friday` etc, etc

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

function getNthBusinessDay(n, month, year) {
    var worked = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        var testDate = new Date(year, month - 1, i);
        var day = testDate.getDay();
        if (day > 0 && day < 6) {
            if (++worked == n) {
                return days[day];
            }
        }
    }
}
```